# Uncommitted Postgresql Row lock

Tags: postgresql, locking, locks

I was wondering if anyone knows how to release a lock from an uncommitted dead function?

Lets say that I have a service that does a lock on a row of data, yet before the lock is commited, I terminate the service. What would happen with the locked row and how would I release the lock? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as the function has ended and the transaction if finished, the locks are gone.

Comment: What about if the function terminated abnormally, so that it never had the chance to finish or close the transaction?

Comment: Don't worry. PostgreSQL rolls back the transaction and releases the locks when the client suddenly disconnects. If the server crashes, it will run crach recovery, which will also undo the transaction.